# Parallel execution taking more time than serial

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I am basically writing code to count if a pair sum is even(among all pairs from 1 to 100000). I wrote a code using pthreads and without pthreads. But the code with pthreads is taking more time than the serial one. Here is my serial code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  long long sum = 0, count = 0, n = 100000;
  auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for(int j = i-1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        sum = i + j;
        if(sum%2 == 0)
            count++;
    }
  cout<<"count is "<<count<<endl;

  auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  double time_taken = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
  time_taken *= 1e-9;
  cout << "Time taken by program is : " << fixed << time_taken << setprecision(9)<<" secs"<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and here is my parallel code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAX_THREAD 3

long long cnt[5] = {0};
long long n = 100000;
int work_per_thread;
int start[] = {1, 60001, 83001, 100001};
void *count_array(void* arg)
{
   int t = *((int*)arg);
   long long sum = 0;
   for(int i = start[t]; i < start[t+1]; i++)
     for(int j = i-1; j >=0; j--)
     {
        sum = i + j;
            if(sum%2 == 0)
                cnt[t]++;
     }
   cout<<"thread"<<t<<" finished work "<<cnt[t]<<endl;
   return NULL;
}


int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[MAX_THREAD];
    int arr[] = {0,1,2};

    long long total_count = 0;
    work_per_thread = n/MAX_THREAD;

   auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
       pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, count_array, &arr[i]);

   for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
       pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

   for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
       total_count += cnt[i];

   cout << "count is " << total_count << endl;

   auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   double time_taken = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
   time_taken *= 1e-9;
   cout << "Time taken by program is : " << fixed << time_taken << setprecision(9)<<" secs"<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

In the parallel code I am creating three threads and 1st thread will be doing its computation from 1 to 60000, 2nd thread from 60001 to 83000 and so on. I have chosen these numbers so that each thread gets to do approximately similar number of computations. The parallel execution takes 10.3 secs whereas serial one takes 7.7 secs. I have 6 cores and 2 threads per core. I also used htop command to check if the required number of threads are running or not and it seems to be working fine. I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: I also recommend you learn about [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) and [`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The all cores in the threaded version compete for cnt[].

Use a local counter inside the loop and copy the result into cnt[t] after the loop is ready.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you elaborate on why exactly using cnt[] instead of a local counter takes more time? My understanding is that every thread is trying to access cnt[] at every iteration and that memory access takes time

Comment: @Mr.Gen It might trash L1 cache because `cnt` fits into a single cache line and looks to be used quite often. The cache is per-core and since all cores are both reading and writing to it, the caches must be repeatedly sync this memory block which is costly compared to not having to do it of course.

Comment: ... and this issue is common enough to have a name, @Mr.Gen: "[false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)".